# Webkit stroke not aligning

Tags: html, css

For some reason the stroke I have on my `<h1>` text is not aligned with the text, it appears a pixel or 2 inside the text. Here is my CSS and HTML code it's pretty simple.

```css
header {
  font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: lightgray;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gears Of War</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <header>
    <h1>GEARS OF WAR</h1>
  </header>
  <body>
    <?php //put your code here ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the html code too

Comment: An example would be nice

Comment: Text-stroke is one of those *experimental* properties that may or may not work as expected based on the font in use. Based upon the font you've chosen, with it's pits and various "grunge" counters... I'd never expect text stroke to look correct... but a visual example here would be helpful. Especially since it's doubtful many use that font.

Comment: If you just want a black outline, using a hard `text-shadow` would probably work better.

Comment: @Scott Here is an example 

https://postimg.org/image/yvworisst/

Comment: So you're adding a black stroke to type on a black background??? Doesn't seem to be necessary to me.

Comment: @Scott It's a grey background, the black stroke to the text creates a nice effect like so. https://postimg.org/image/7643miqb9/ This is a page I was working on but got deleted so im trying to recreate it

Comment: Some would argue that `#1a1a1a` may as well be black. :) And you could use hard text-shadows since the `text-shadow` property is *much* better supported.

Comment: @Scott Well I think the darker shade around the text creates a nice subtle effect :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding a `text-shadow` to each side but this is not really good..

And using the experimental `filter:drop-shadow()` property won't be better. Try with `text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;`